# MySQL connection in ASP.NET references Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have some code written that is attempting to connect to a mysql db.
I have installed [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html).
I have added a reference which is MySql.Data.CF.dll in the project.
The project compiles with no complaints.

When I execute this...

```
string conn_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLServer"].ConnectionString;
DataSet m_Dst = new DataSet();
DataTable All_Table = new DataTable();
try
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(m_SQL, new MySqlConnection(conn_str));
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter MyDa = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    MyDa.Fill(m_Dst);
    if (m_Dst.Tables.Count > 0)
        All_Table = m_Dst.Tables[0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string s = ex.Message;
}
```

I get an exception as follows:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MySql.Data.CF" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

Does anyone know what I am missing or have done wrong to prevent this connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try re-installing the MySql Connector.

Then I would re-write that code like this:

```
string conn_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLServer"].ConnectionString;

DataTable All_Table = new DataTable();
using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlconnection(conn_str))
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(m_SQL, cn))
{
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            All_Table.Load(rdr);
            rdr.Close();
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

You need to be sure you dispose your connection, and the using blocks will do that.

Comment: Yea i plan on disposing it but i was just testing this. And I get this error. I already tried reinstalling so that isnt the solution either. Other ideas ?

Comment: I'd take the error message at face value.  It's complaining about culture/satellite assemblies, and so I'd make sure the localized version of connector matches your system, or that you've included any needed localization assemblies with the deployment.

Comment: btw, you can use `cn.CreateCommand()` instead `new MySqlCommand(,)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My problem was that I wasn't adding the refference from the **.NET panel** but from the **Browse panel**.
After I Installed verion 6.2.3.0 I added the refference from the **.NET panel**.
It worked like a charm.